# Not able to start mpirun with subprocess.Popen

Tags: python, subprocess, mpi, pipe

I'm following the instructions [here](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/ResearchComputing/FRCRC-2013/blob/master/many_task/mpi.ipynb).

What happens is, `wait` or `communicate` return immediately and don't wait for the mpi process to finish. I do this in a separate thread in my python application. When I do this interactively in a python shell it seems to sometimes work. Perhaps I have to wait after the `Popen` and before the `wait`/`communicate`?

I'm calling `Popen` as the following:

```
mpicmd = 'mpirun -n 2 --hostfile hostfile ' + executable + ' ' + mpiArgs
mpirun = subprocess.Popen(mpicmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
out, err = mpirun.communicate()
```

When I run mpirun from my program I get:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
There are no allocated resources for the application 
  rttl
that match the requested mapping:
  hostfile

Verify that you have mapped the allocated resources properly using the 
--host or --hostfile specification.
```

When I do it interactively (in the same directory) it works.

Also tried:

```
mpirun = subprocess.Popen(['mpirun', '-n', '2', '--hostfile', 'hostfile', 'rttl', '10000'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

and got the same results.

Comment: Maybe you can give a few more details (some lines of code?). What you described so far seems to work pretty well. `wait/communicate` are blocking and waiting for the process to terminate.

Comment: I added more details, see edit.

Comment: I would check if both versions are really running in the same directory. Maybe add `ls -l;` to the `mpicmd`. And check if `$PATH` and `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` are the same in both versions.

Answer (score 1):

I just faced the same problem. I was writing the contents of my hostfile to file like such:

```
myfile = open("hostfile", "w")
myfile.write("localhost")
```

And then I was calling the MPI command. The problem was that I forgot the `myfile.close()` command... Adding that before my MPI command fixed it for me.

I know it's an old post, but maybe someone might bump into the same issue

Comment: This was very helpful and solved my problem. Adding a `.close()` wrote the file to disk. Happy new year. :)